# How to extract the number in the string "Task(12345)" with Regular Expression and Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

How to extract the number in the string "Task(12345)" with Regular Expression and Powershell? I tried the following, but no chance.

```
$file = gc myfile.txt
$matches = ([regex]"Task\(\d{1,5}\)").matches($file)
# Get a list of numbers
```

Could someone please help me to find the correct regular expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to get all occurances in the file?  If so I would do the following

```
$r = "^Task\((\d+)\)$"
$res = gc myFile.txt | 
  ?{ $_ -match $r } |
  %{ $_ -match $r | out-null ; $matches[1] }
```

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind that Select-String makes this a one-liner:

```
PS> Select-String 'Task\((?<num>\d{1,5})\)' myfile.txt | 
        %{$_.matches[0].Groups['num'].value}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly 5 digits in there you could use:

```
^Task\([\d{1,5}]{5}\)$
```

Otherwise for an arbitrary number of digits go with:

```
^Task\([\d{1,5}]+\)$
```

Comment: For the arbitrary number of digis, why not just ^Task\\([\d+\\)$ ?

Comment: It doesn't work. The Task number are a little bit every where in a source file.