# Extract number from a variable in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am very new to powershell and am trying to extract a number from a variable. For instance, I get the list of ports using this command:
$ports = [system.io.ports.serialport]::getportnames()

The contents of $ports is: COM1, COM2, COM10, COM16 and so on.

I want to extract the numbers from $ports. I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139168/how-to-extract-the-number-in-the-string-task12345-with-regular-expression-an). It does what I want, but reads from a file.

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Edit: I was able to do what I wanted as follows:

```
 $port=COM20

 $port=$port.replace("COM","")
```

But if there is any other way to do this, I will be happy to learn it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a quick way would be

```
$portlist = [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::GetPortNames() -replace 'COM'
```

If you want it to be a list of integers and not numeric strings, then you can use

```
[int[]] $portlist = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
# initialize the variable that we want to use to store the port numbers.
$portList = @()

# foreach object returned by GetPortNames...
[IO.Ports.SerialPort]::GetPortNames() | %{
    # replace the pattern "COM" at the beginning of the string with an empty
    # string, just leaving the number.  Then add the number to our array.
    $portList += ($_ -ireplace "^COM", [String]::Empty)
}
```

Note that I used `[IO.Ports.SerialPort]` instead of `[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]`.  These are the same things - PowerShell implicitly assumes that you're working with the `[System]` namespace, so you don't need to specify it explicitly, though there's nothing wrong with doing it.

**Edit** 
To answer your questions:

`%{...}` is shorthand for `foreach-object {...}`.

`$_` indicates the object that is currently in the pipeline.  When we're inside a `foreach-object` block, `$_` resolves to the one object out of the entire collection that we're currently dealing with.

If we write my code a bit differently, I think it'll be easier to understand.  Between these examples, `$_` and `$port` are the same things.

```
$portList = @()
foreach ($port in [IO.Ports.SerialPorts]::GetPortNames()) {
    $portList += ($port -ireplace "^COM", [String]::Empty)
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I have 2 follow-up questions: 1. What is the use of %{} and 2. what does $_ mean?

Comment: `%` is an alias for `foreach` or `foreach-object` so `%{}` = for each item passed into the pipeline, do what's inside the curly braces. And $_ refers to the current object in the pipeline, in this case the current line/port being inspected

Answer (score 1):

This should cover it:

```
$portnos = $ports | foreach {$_ -replace 'COM',''}
```