# How to extract a list of numbers using Powershell Regex?

Tags: regex, powershell

My question is similar to the below question but with more complexity I guess.

**[How to extract the number in the string “Task(12345)” with Regular Expression and Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139168/how-to-extract-the-number-in-the-string-task12345-with-regular-expression-an)**

My text that I need to extract number from looks like:

```
************************
 multi-line bulk texts 
************************
Change 11111 on 2013/12/09 by someone
************************
 multi-line bulk texts 
************************
Change 22222 on 2013/12/09 by someone
************************
 multi-line bulk texts 
************************
Change 33333 on 2013/12/09 by someone
************************
 multi-line bulk texts 
************************
Change 33333 on 2013/12/09 by someone
************************
 multi-line bulk texts 
************************
...[etc. same pattern]
```

The bulk texts could contain any characters but I am not interested in it. What I need to extract is the change numbers (11111, 22222, ...) and store them in a variable or output to a text file.

Can someone guide me through that? I've tested a bunch regex but no luck yet :(

Thanks,

Comment: The regex is simple:  '(?<=Change\s+)\b\d+\b'  If you want code, the guidelines indicate that you should post the code that you have tried, the results, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the file is huge, you can do the whole file at once using chained -match -replace operations:

```
$regex = '^Change\s(\d+)\son.+'
(get-content file.txt -r 0) -match $regex -replace $regex,'$1'
```

Comment: Works like magic, I learned a lot from your piece of code! Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with .net or powershell, but you could use this regex:

```
(\d)\1+
```

or if the numbers have always this length

```
(\d)\1{4}
```

Have a look at this site for explanation of this particular expression. http://regex101.com/r/gN9vM4
Also useful for trying out new stuff

Comment: Thanks for the online regex extractor

Answer (score 0):

Many ways of doing this... I suggest the following:

`\d+(?=.*\d{4}(?:\/\d{2})*\sby\s\w+)`

Which checks for the "2013/12/09 by someone" after the match.